# Azure Application proxy and AD Connect/Pass though authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are using on-prem and Azure cloud separately and planning to make connection between on-prem AD and Azure AD by using Azure AD connect or Pass-though authentication (preview).

My question is, If we use Azure AD connect or pass-though ,will there be any need to use Azure application proxy in any case?

Under what scenario/application integration, both application proxy and Azure AD connect/pass-through will be required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we use Azure AD connect or pass-though ,will there be any need to
>   use Azure application proxy in any case?

By default, there is **no** need to deploy a proxy for Azure AD connect. It depends on your local network, if your On-prem server(AAD connect installed) can connect to the internet direct, we should not deploy the proxy.

> Under what scenario/application integration, both application proxy
>   and Azure AD connect/pass-through will be required?

This table describes the ports and protocols that are required for communication between the Azure AD Connect server and on-premises AD:
[image]

More information about hybrid identity required ports and protocols, please refer to this official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-ports).

If your on-prem network can't open those ports, we need to deploy a proxy for it.

Comment: Thanks Jason,If I use application proxy ,will application endpoint available/published over internet so user can sign into application  without VPN (through Azure AD) ?

Comment: @A_____ yes, user can sign into application without VPN.

Comment: @A_____ Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thanks again Jason.So we can summaries like this ,if we need on prem applications sso ONLY with Azure AD  then application proxy is the solution.And if we use Azure AD Connect/pass-through it will give application sso plus ad sync

Comment: @A_____ if we need on prem  applications sso Only with Azure AD, we can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications) to add this application to Azure AD, there is no need application proxy. the application proxy only work for your network can't open more ports, need expose this application to public.